# eclipse cannot find main method from given launch configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, manifest.mf

I went to eclipse>export>java>runnable jar file

I changed launch configuration to my project name; destination: desktop.

I tried all three library handling options:

1. extract required folders into generated JAR
2. Package required libraries into generated JAR
3. copy required files into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR.

I did not check anything to do with "ANT scripts".

When I pressed "finish" in the export window, eclipse gave me a error: "Could not find main method from given launch configuration". After pressing the "finish" button in the eclipse export window, the next button was grayed out. It created a JAR file at the destination. When I tried to open it Mac's Jar Launcher (default)(13.5.0), it gave me the message:

> The Java JAR file "filename.jar" could not be launched.
>
> Check the Console for possible error messages.

I googled this and some people said to check the manifest.mf file. I extracted it, then: "META-INF>manifest.mf". I opened manifest.mf with textedit.
Inside manifest.mf were the lines:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ acm.jar
>
> Class-Path: .

I am running Mac OSx 10.6.8 snow leopard. I have the latest java available for snow leopard (I think my java is the one just BEFORE java 7).

Also, I'm trying to export a project with:

1. a .java file that contains all my code
2. acm.jar
3. java.policy.applet
4. Scores.txt

My .java file contains a `public void run() {}` and JFrames/JPanels. My .java file extends ConsoleProgram.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no `public static void main(String[] args)` method, the virtual machine (Java) will not know where to start your program. It sounds like your `run()` method is what you want to start your program. If so, then add (to your main class (.java)) a method: `public static void main(String[] args)`. Re-export your .jar, making sure the launch configuration is set to your Project name, and your main class.